# Bitwise AND Operation between multiple rows Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bitwise-and

I would like to perform AND operations between multiple rows of a Pandas Dataframe by only reading the indices of the rows. For example:

```py
    def f(df, indices):
        result = df.iloc[indices[0]]
        for i in range(1,len(indices)):
            result = result & df.iloc[indices[i]]
        return result

    df = pd.DataFrame([[7, 7, 7, 8], [1, 2, 4, 8], [13, 2, 13, 13], [1, 7, 14, 13]])
    indices = [0,1,3]
    result = f(df, indices)
    print(result)
```

Is there an efficient way to perform this operation? I would like to perform this operation by also considering other lists of indices. I tried to perform this operation with the **apply()** function of Pandas Dataframe, however, I was only able to consider a fixed number of indices without generalizing the operation:

```py
result = df.apply(lambda c: (c[0] & c[1]  & c[3]), axis=0)
result_1 = df.apply(lambda c: (c[0] & c[2]), axis=0)
result_2 = df.apply(lambda c: (c[1] & c[2]  & c[3]), axis=0)
#...
```

Comment: The second snippet represents an example of the type of operation that I would like to generalize. I revised it to further clarify the problem.

Comment: @Stefano Do you mean something like `functools.reduce(np.bitwise_and, df.iloc[indices].values)` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, this could be a solution. However, I have doubts about the efficiency of the reduce function. Generally, the reduce function is O(n^2), however, I could have thousands and thousands of items for each row, and I don't know if this function would be an efficient solution.

Comment: @Stefano `numpy.bitwise_and` has `.reduce` method: `np.bitwise_and.reduce(df.iloc[indices].values)` You can try it.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, but the problem is the complexity of these solutions.